# Como puedo eliminar los corchetes o realizar obtener los mismo resultados como un Objeto?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Me encuentro realizando un recetario web, para un proyecto de la universidad, pero para realizar el CRUD de los post o recetas necesito consultar a la base de datos los elementos relacionados, por ejemplo de un post necesito, toda la informacion del post, el creador, likes y los comentarios.

```
   $querry = (new static)::with( [
        'user',
        'likes',
        'comments' => function($query){
            $query->with('user:id,name,nick_name,profile_photo_path');
        }
        
    ])
    ->where('id','=',$id)
    ->get();
```

La cosa, esq los modelos de likes y comments, me aparecen con corchetes y no me permite realizar una consulta de forma correcta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien lo intente con el metodo `join()` pero no me sale organizado como lo necesito. si me pueden ayudar estaria agradecido

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta... si la respuesta te la da en corchetes es porque es un arreglo de varios elementos, osea varios `likes` o varios `comments`, que es lo que esperas que te traiga solo un elemento?

Comment: hazle un foreach para traer los elementos uno por uno ```
foreach($querry as $query_item){ $query_item
}